# Turning off jQuery Accordion Auto sizing

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery UI accordion control to present some information to my users.  Some of the data in the accordion panes is more "paragraph" in nature and some of the panes simply contain a list of items.  When the "paragraph" type of information is displayed in a pane, the control fills the size of the container div.  However, when the user switches to pane that has list type of data, the accordion control shrinks to fit the smaller content.  I don't want it to do that. I want it to ALWAYS fill 100% of the container div. I've tried turning off animations, setting the width to 100%, turning off, setting fillSpace: true, none of it works.  Here's my html / css

**HTML**

```
<section id="view-right">
    <div id="letters-accordion">
        <h3>Summary</h3>
        <div class="accordion-content-custom">
            <asp:Literal id="litSummary" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <h3>Categories</h3>
        <div class="accordion-content-custom">
            <asp:Repeater id="rptCategories" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <ul>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li><asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /></li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
        <h3>Collection</h3>
        <div class="accordion-content-custom">
            <asp:Panel id="pnlInstitution" runat="server">
                <span class="label">Institution:</span>
                <asp:Label id="lblInstitution" runat="server" CssClass="data" />
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel id="pnlCollection" runat="server" CssClass="accordion-field-set">
                <span class="label">Collection:</span>
                <asp:Label id="lblCollection" runat="server" CssClass="data" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
        <h3>How to Cite</h3>
        <div class="accordion-content-custom">
            <asp:Placeholder id="plcCiteAuthor" runat="server">
                <asp:Literal id="litCiteAuthorName" runat="server" />
            </asp:Placeholder>. 
            "<asp:Literal id="litCiteTitle" runat="server" />". <em>Letters of 1916</em>. Schreibman, Susan, Ed. Maynooth University: 2016. Website.
            <asp:HyperLink id="lnkCiteURL" runat="server" />.
        </div>
        <h3>Share on Social Media</h3>
        <div class="accordion-content-custom">
            <div class="fb-share-button" data-href='<%= this.LetterURL %>' data-layout="button"></div>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"{count} data-text="Check out this letter from the Letters of 1916 project" data-via="letters1916" data-hashtags="Letters1916">Tweet</a>
            <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.accordion-content-custom {
  color: black !important; }
  .accordion-content-custom .label {
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 3px; }
  .accordion-content-custom .data {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px; }

#letters-accordion {
  width: 98%;
  min-width: 98%;
  margin-left: 15px; }

#view-right {
  float: right;
  max-width: 39%;
  margin-right: 10px; }
  #view-right h2 {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #998b77; }
```

Comment: You mean that for example your "Categories" -pane is narrower than the others? I can't replicate the problem. Maybe expand your example code to cover also the `<div id="letters-accordion">` 's parent and relevant css.

Comment: Hi Sami - yes that's exactly the problem. My "Categories" pane becomes narrower than my "Summary" pane when you click on it (I want it to stay the same width).  I've updated the code to include the outer HTML for that section as well as the relevant css classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the width is changing is the `max-width` attribute on the `<section>` combined with `float`. When float is set, the container automatically shrinks to fit the content. In this case, the list takes less room than other content and the section automatically shrinks when that accordion container is the one selected open.
I think you have 2 options to deal with this.

**Method 1**
Set the width of the `section` explicitly. Ie. change the `max-width` to `width`.

**Method 2**
If you want to keep the `section` as narrow as possible, but still have all content displayed with same width, read the widths of all containers with jQuery on load, and set the width of all containers to the largest one. Something like

```
var largest = 0;
$("#letters-accordion").children($("div")).each(function () {
    if ($(this).width() > largest)
    {
        largest = $(this).width();
    }
});
$("#letters-accordion").children($("div")).each(function() {
    $(this).width(largest);
});
```

I recommend Mehtod 1 for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks! I went with method 1 and it worked beautifully!